# Higher-order function composition notation

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I'm working with this higher-order compose function:

```
fun <T, U, V> higherCompose(): ((U) -> V) -> ((T) -> U) -> (T) -> V =
    { f ->
        { g ->
            { x -> f(g(x)) }
        }
    }
```

And the application:

```
 val cos = higherCompose<Double, Double, Double>()()
{ x: Double -> Math.sin(x)}() { x : Double -> Math.PI/2  - x }
```

I do understand what we're trying to achieve here mathematically. But what I'm struggling with is notation and the programming meaning:

What exactly is

```
higherCompose<Double>()
```

And why do we apply so strangely values to it:

```
1. () () 
2. { function1} { function 1}
```

Comment: `<Double, Double, Double>` is just supplying the generic types `T`, `U` and `V`. The calls are because it's higher-order - it's a function that takes functions and returns functions.

Comment: I don't get why we need to do the second call in order to provide 2 arguments. I

Comment: Which do you think is the second call? You call `higherCompose` once with no arguments to get the function it creates, then you call *that* function with a lambda, returning another function, then you call *that* function with another lambda, returning the final function, that you can call with a number.

Comment: I think it the answer that I've been looking for. I was struggling with proper reading the expression.

Comment: Maybe `val cos = higherCompose<Double, Double, Double>()({ x: Double -> Math.sin(x) })({ x : Double -> Math.PI/2  - x })` would be clearer; the convention of moving the lambda out of the parentheses if it's the last argument is perhaps unhelpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how this notation is parsed and what the function calls are:

```
higherCompose<Double, Double, Double>()() { x -> Math.sin(x) }() { x -> Math.PI/2  - x }
|                                    ^| ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^| ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^|
|                                    1| 2          3         | 4           5           | 
|_____________________________________|______________________|_________________________|
| first call                          | second call          | third call              |
```

1. This is the initial no-argument call to `higherCompose` that returns a value of exactly the `higherCompose`'s return type, `((U) -> V) -> ((T) -> U) -> (T) -> V`, with the three type parameters substituted with `Double`.
2. These parentheses are simply used to resolve parsing ambiguity. Kotlin allows calling a function with a lambda in either of the forms: `f({ })`, `f() { }`, `f { }`. If you remove the parentheses, the lambda marked as (3) will be treated as an argument to the first call. One way to solve this ambiguity is to add `()` to tell the compiler that it's the (1)'s return value that is invoked and not `higherCompose`
3. Therefore, this lambda is passed as the `((U) -> V)` argument to the `higherCompose`'s result type, producing `((T) -> U) -> (T) -> V`.
4. These parentheses are added because Kotlin does not allow calling a return value of a call with a lambda outside parentheses (`f() { }`) directly with another lambda: `f() { } { }` is prohibited, but adding another pair of parentheses between the lambdas solves this: `f() { }() { }` means an invocation of the `f`'s result with a lambda.
5. This lambda is passed as the `((T) -> U)` argument to the (3)'s result type, and the result of this call is `(T) -> V`

You can get a much less cryptic version of this expression if you pass all the lambdas inside parentheses (the `f({ })` form instead of `f() { }` or `f { }`):

```
higherCompose<Double, Double, Double>()({ x -> Math.sin(x) })({ x -> Math.PI / 2 - x })
```

See: [Lambda Expressions and Anonymous Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) in the language reference.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle function composition in Kotlin is to use an extension function on the function type.  Try something like this:

```
infix fun <P1, R1, R2> ((P1) -> R1).then(f: ((R1)-> R2)) : (P1) -> R2 {
    return { p1 : P1 -> f(this(p1)) }
}
```

This allows you to use a simpler construct in your code:

```
function1 then function1
```

Using your example above you can do:

```
infix fun <P1, R1, R2> ((P1) -> R1).then(f: ((R1)-> R2)) : (P1) -> R2 {
    return { p1 : P1 -> f(this(p1)) }
}

fun main() {
    val c = { x: Double -> Math.sin(x)} then { x : Double -> Math.PI/2  - x }
    println(c(2.4))
}
```

which prints `0.8953331462437456`.

Check out my [Functional FizzBuzz post](https://softwaredesignmuse.wordpress.com/2019/04/15/functional-fizzbuzz/) which uses this approach.